# How to use AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute with a bluetooth device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-audio

I'm developing an app that plays and records, I wonder if it is possible to use a `Bluetooth` device with the `AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute`, and if the answer is Yes, How to record from two devices like the iPhone built-in microphone and a `Bluetooth` microphone? because I couldn't find any tutorial or example to do this.

Comment: After spending quite some time trying to make it work I can say that this seems to be impossible. Manual input route change makes it also switch output.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Is a shame that the bluetooth is always set as pairs. This limits very much functionality also the bluetooth microphones are usually of bad quality.

Comment: Microphone quality - is what bothers me also... There is a new category AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute (ios 6.0 and later), according to the docs it should do what we want, but... it doesn't work with bluetooth! That's sad. 
Please let me know if you find something about it.